Ryu controller unable to dispath data packets to host
I am trying to send a ping message to a host via a Ryu controller but I am not getting the response on mininet . Here is the code I have written
This is method under SimpleSwitch13:
    def send_packet_to_host(self, eth_dst, out_port):
        # Get the datapath
        datapath = self.datapaths.get(1)

        if datapath is None:
            print(f"No datapath found with id = 1")
            return
        
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

        # Create an Ethernet frame
        pkt = packet.Packet()
        pkt.add_protocol(ethernet.ethernet(ethertype=ether.ETH_TYPE_IP,
                                        dst=eth_dst))
        
        # Create an output action to send the packet
        actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port)]

        # Create a flow mod message to install a flow entry in the switch
        out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath,
                                buffer_id=ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER,
                                in_port=ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,
                                actions=actions,
                                data=pkt)
        
        # Send the packet out of the specified port
        datapath.send_msg(out)

Trying to send data packet .
should ping the host and display on mininet or ryu controller.

Given codes make the controller send a command to datapath, and this command tells datapath to send a packet to specified out_port. If this is what you want, you have to create a packet with content which host can understand, rather than a blank packet. I mean the pkt
